# Arba'a Veshishim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred sixty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

164 are the number of parshiot in the book of Shemot. (Rambam, Hil. Sefer Torah, 8:4)

Answer (score 3):

(I'm counting phrases hyphenated in the cantillation as comprising separate words and not one each.)

*Yitzchak* gave several blessings: Genesis 27:27–29, 27:39–40, 28:3–4. Outside of these, he spoke 164 words recorded in the Torah:

- 7 in 22:7
- 2 in 26:7
- 5 in 26:9
- 7 in 26:22
- 8 in 26:27
- 1 in 27:1
- 7 in 27:2
- 11 in 27:3
- 13 in 27:4
- 4 in 27:18
- 5 in 27:20
- 10 in 27:21
- 6 in 27:22
- 4 in 27:24
- 8 in 27:25
- 5 in 27:26
- 2 in 27:32
- 15 in 27:33
- 5 in 27:35
- 18 in 27:37
- 5 in 28:1
- 16 in 28:2

(I'm not counting 28:6, which is merely quoting/paraphrasing him.)

Comment: How many words are in the blessings, by contrast?

How in the world did you think "164" and come up with this?

Comment: @R'IM, I had how many words were in the blessings, but don't any longer, I'm afraid. But you can count them: there are only seven verses' worth.  :-)

Comment: As to how I came up with this: When searching for an answer to a previous question in this series, I found, I forget where, the claim that there were [some number of] words of Yitzchak's outside of his blessings. (I forget the number as well.) Not believing it, I counted, and discovered that the correct number is 164. So I hung on to the info until you asked this question.  :-)

Comment: @IsaacMoses: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15418

Answer (score 1):

Yitzchok was 164 years old when Yosef became Bar Mitzva.

Yaakov was 91 when Yosef was born, Yitzchok was 151 when Yosef was born.
151 + 13 = 164

Comment: Mazal Tov! Yaakov's "ben zekunim" must have gotten quite a party.