# Arba'a Ve'arba'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred forty-four?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Shavu'a Tov, and happy La"G Ba'omer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

244  is the difference between the Christian and Jewish timelines (Seder Ha'olam vs the  Bishop Ussher Timeline)

Comment: They differ from one another by 244 years?

Comment: Yep.  Seder Olam says the world was created in 3760 BCE, and the King James says 4004 BCE

Comment: The King James says nothing of the sort. That's Bishop Ussher you're thinking of.

Comment: @TRiG Thanks, but next time feel free to edit the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

*Yitzchak* spoke 244 words that are recorded in the *Tora*:

- the 164 listed at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5221
- 8 in *B'reshis* 27:27
- 10 in 27:28
- 16 in 27:29
- 8 in 27:39
- 13 in 27:40
- 9 in 28:3
- 16 in 28:4

(I'm counting phrases hyphenated in the cantillation as comprising separate words and not one each.)

Answer (score 2):

.............................גמרא      =      244

Answer (score 1):

[Reportedly](http://books.google.com/books?id=MFn3KeENnA0C&pg=PA425&dq=244), the Nazis killed 244 Jews in Henichesk, the Ukraine, in the fall of 1941.